Has anyone experienced "(failed)net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT" for a single website on a single computer?
I deployed an Express app on AWS Lightsail. However, after sometime I always run into this error where I cannot connect to my app.  (failed)net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
This occurs only for the website I deployed and only for my computer (on any browser). I can access the site on my phone or another computer. It also only happens randomly and I need to fix the problem by restarting the express server.
Does anyone know what the problem is?
My url is foo.com and my backend is accessed from foo.com:4000/api
